# Visual Studio error C3409 in header file while compiling C

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have a working code with a function in it. while compiling without the function declaration in the header, it works.
While compiling with the function declaration in the header, I get a number of errors (screenshot included)

Function Declaration:

```
int get_number_of_possibilities(Item inventory[], double money, int size);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Item` is  not defined, you need to `include` the file where it was declared. Next time post the code here, we have a great bandwidth :)

Comment: The prototype `void print(i)` is wrong too.

Comment: I can be wrong, but `Item inventory[]` as argument looks like invalid C.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the type of `Item` cannot be resolved by the compiler, you should include the header that defines it in the header that declares the `get_number_of_possibilities` function.